# WooCommerce - Display variations of "POA" for products with no price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'd like to run this by the community to see what others are doing for products without prices

WooCommerce has gotten rid of the  *"Free!"* label they used to use for products with no price entered.  I would like to now show *"POA"* or *"Coming Soon"* or something to that effect for these products

I can do this at present by using the following code:

```
// Change empty (not zeroed) prices to "Coming Soon"
add_filter('woocommerce_empty_price_html', 'noprice_callout');

function noprice_callout() {
    return 'Coming Soon';
}
```

However, I want to take this a step further whereby **only** on the product page where the price should be I'll show *"Coming Soon - Contact us"* hyperlinked to the contact page, but everywhere else *(product search form, category pages, etc...)*, I want to show just the *"Coming Soon"* text without the URL.

Could someone suggest how to do this only on the product single?

I need to understand what's happening with variable products too as WooCommerce returns *"Sorry, this product is unavailable..."* when no value is present for variation price but if 0.00 is entered, it works and can be ordered like any other product. I can edit my code above to include "0.00" prices which would get me around variable products handling but I'd rather stick with using just "blank" prices.

Comment: Ask only one question per question, please.  Yours contains two questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer your *first question*.  If you have multiple questions, please ask them in separate questions.

What you want is the [is_product()](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/) function.  It returns whether it's a single product being displayed, or not:

```
// Change empty (not zeroed) prices to "Coming Soon"
add_filter('woocommerce_empty_price_html', 'noprice_callout');

function noprice_callout() {
    if ( is_product() ) {
        // return a link ONLY when viewing the product page
        return '<a href="contactus.php">Contact Us</a>';
    } else {
        // otherwise return some standard text
        return 'Coming Soon';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks cale_b... that done it! Apologies re. the double question too, the second part was more me rambling to myself than a question. I'll come back with a question on it when I do a bit more digging

Comment: Having implemented this fully today, I see a problem cropping up. My "callout" - which is now a full-fledged button carried in using it's shortcode - is also appearing in place of the "POA" text line which was to be applied to products everywhere else. It seems to only occur after the actual callout appears for the first time and then I guess the browser is applying it everywhere from cache